# skip pam_fprintd.so with closed lid

Tags: pam, acpi

I really love fprintd and I really love having my laptop closed while in docking station. But I hate both together. This is my `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_fprintd.so
auth            required        pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
```

Any idea how I can make it happen that `pam_fprintd.so` is skipped while my laptop's lid is closed?

Comment: It's almost the same question as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678609/how-to-disable-fingerprint-authentication-when-laptop-lid-is-closed