# How to disable fingerprint authentication when laptop lid is closed?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, pam, acpi, fingerprint

I recently managed to make fingerprint authentication work on my laptop, thanks to the [Goodix Linux Development](https://discord.com/invite/6xZ6k34Vqg) discord community and the  github users Infinytum and Michael Teuscher on the `driver/538d` branch on https://github.com/infinytum/libfprint/tree/driver/538d.

But after enabling fingerprint for login with `fprintd-enroll` and for `sudo` access with `sudo pam-auth-update` I noticed a problem:

Whenever I am using an external monitor to work, and the lid is closed, I have to wait for the fingerprint authentication to time out, before being able to type the `sudo` password, which causes a delay of several seconds:

```bsh
username@host:~/ron/libfprint$ sudo ls
Place your finger on the fingerprint reader
Place your finger on the reader again
Place your finger on the reader again
Place your finger on the reader again
Verification timed out
[sudo] password for username:
```

How can I disable fingerprint authentication when the laptop lid is closed, so I can type the `sudo` password without waiting for the fingerprint to time out?

Answer (score 13):

To disable fingerprint authentication when the laptop lid is closed, and re-enable when it is reopened, we will use `acpid` to bind to the `button/lid.*` event to a custom script that will stop and mask the `fprintd` service on lid close, and unmask and start the `fprintd` service on lid open.

We also check that the HDMI cable is connected by testing the contents of `/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/status`.

Follow the steps below:

1. Create file `/etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh` with the following contents:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   lock=$HOME/fprint-disabled

   if grep -Fq closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state &&
      grep -Fxq connected /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/status
   then
     touch "$lock"
     systemctl stop fprintd
     systemctl mask fprintd
   elif [ -f "$lock" ]
   then
     systemctl unmask fprintd
     systemctl start fprintd
     rm "$lock"
   fi
   ```
2. Make the file executable with

   ```bsh
   chmod +x /etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh
   ```
3. Create file `/etc/acpi/events/laptop-lid` with the following contents:

   ```bsh
   event=button/lid.*
   action=/etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh
   ```
4. Restart the `acpid` service with:

   ```bsh
   sudo service acpid restart
   ```

Now the fingerprint will be used only when the lid is open.

In order to restore the correct state of the `fprintd` service if you disconnect/reconnect while the laptop is off, you may call the above script from a `systemd` init file. The steps to do this are the following:

1. Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/laptop-lid.service` with the following contents:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Laptop Lid
   After=suspend.target

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   WantedBy=suspend.target
   ```
2. Reload the systemd config files with

   ```bsh
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
3. Start the service with

   ```bsh
   sudo systemctl start laptop-lid.service
   ```
4. Enable the service so that it starts automatically on boot

   ```bsh
   sudo systemctl enable laptop-lid.service
   ```

Now the status should be correct even after connecting/disconnecting when the computer is off.

References used for creating the code in the answer:

- [How to run a script when the lid is closed?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1140362/136621)
- [Laptop doesn't hibernate when I close the lid in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/518825/136621)
- [Catch lid close and open events](https://askubuntu.com/a/526003/136621)

Comment: This is a self-answered question, because I though it would be useful to share with other community members that may be facing the same problem. But I am interested in better/more efficient solutions, so feel free to post more answers and/or suggest improvements on this answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm for my (docked) XPS 13 9310!

Comment: You're welcome @BenjaminBarrois, I updated the script with some changes that I made, so that it avoids some race conditions, and also activates only when the HDMI cable is connected.

Comment: I'm having a problem when I switch my computer off while lid closed and start it back with lid open. When I do that, then I see no user on Ubuntu's login screen, I think it is because of the fprintd service remaining unstarted. Maybe there should be some actions triggered at startup to correct that?

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois: See updated answer, I forgot to include that initially.

Comment: Great! This is exactly the system I used to have to change my CPU governor when plugging in or out my AC adpater.

Comment: My machine has a displayport not an HDMI so I needed to use ``` /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status``` instead. Amazing post though - thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

Fingerprint auth in Linux works through [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM), there is `pam_fprintd.so` module which talks to `fprintd` service. When `fprintd` service isn't working, `pam_fprintd` fails to communicate with it, and PAM auth skips to the next module in the config. But another PAM module could also skip over `pam_fprintd`.

So suppose you have `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` with the following contents:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_fprintd.so
auth            required        pam_unix.so
```

Your real config could be different or even in a different location, but what's crucial is `pam_fprintd` and `pam_unix`, which does password  auth.

What you could do is add another entry into config, just before `pam_fprintd.so` which would skip that module if LID is closed. One way to achieve this is via [pam_exec.so](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_exec.8.html) module. Create an executable script `/usr/local/bin/pam_check_lid` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
LID_STATE=$(cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ')

case ${LID_STATE} in
    closed)
    echo closed
    exit 1
    ;;
    open*)
    echo open
    exit 0
    ;;
    *)
    # LID is open by default
    echo unknown
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

**IMPORTANT**: ensure that this file isn't globally writable. Otherwise, you might introduce a security vulnerability into your system. Also, you can check LID status over dbus, for details check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551220/147806).

And then add the following line, just before `pam_fprintd`:

```
auth   [success=ignore default=1]   pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/bin/pam_check_lid
```

So your config would look like this:

```
auth   [success=ignore default=1]  pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/bin/pam_check_lid
auth   sufficient                  pam_fprintd.so
auth   required                    pam_unix.so
```

Now PAM auth would execute your script before attempting fingerprint auth, and if your script returns non-zero exit code (fails) it would do the default action, which skips 1 entry in a PAM config (so it skips `pam_fprintd` to the next auth which is `pam_unix`). When LID is open, it will return `0` exit code,  and on success it wouldn't do anything, because of the `ignore` keyword in a config.

Alternatively, instead of `pam_exec.so` with a script, you can make your own PAM module with the same behavior as a script.

Few notes on debugging and actually implementing this. If you're having issues with `pam_exec`, you can add debugging options like `debug` and `log`, for details check `pam_exec` [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_exec.8.html). It is also good to test your changes on a new PAM config, instead of modifying an existing one, since a mistake in a config might lock you from your account. For example, you can just copy your `system-auth` as `system-auth-new` and work on `system-auth-new` and then replace it when it's tested. And for testing you could use [pamtester](https://pamtester.sourceforge.net/). For example:

```
cp /etc/pam.d/system-auth /etc/pam.d/system-auth-new
# UPDATE /etc/pam.d/system-auth-new
pamtester system-auth-new YOUR_USER_NAME authenticate
```

And when it works as intended, replace `system-auth` with your new config.

Comment: On my laptop, the state is at `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state`